# Is there a way to check socket available data, synchronously?

Tags: c#, sockets, events

i want to check the socket available data to read, before i call the receive() method. but it is not working. i think the way i am checking the socket available data is not correct. this is the code:

```
 private Socket _clientSocket;               //Client socket

  public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Check for data available before calling Receive().
        if (_clientSocket.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            Receive();
        }


    }
```

it is giving me this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

what is the correct way to check socket available data to read? I am thinking some kind of events but i can't figure it out..

any help?

EDIT:
Button for connection:

```
   private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string ip = TboxIP.Text;
            int port = int.Parse(TboxPort.Text);
            _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            // Connect to the  host
            _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);

            if (SocketConnected(_clientSocket) == true)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Socket Connection Established .. ";
            }


        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code that initialises _clientSocket

Comment: @Gary, i just edited. there is a connect button that initializes the _clientSocket.

Answer (score 2):

That's your problem, you are accessing _clientSocket in the Form1 constructor and it has not been initialised yet.

Comment: even if i initialize it in Form1, the program waits for indefinite amount of time, while the socket is not connected. so it is blocking the whole UI thread.

Comment: @Liban then perhaps you should perform the connect on a background thread

Answer (score 2):

Look documentation: [Socket.Poll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)
if you set the microsecond number to negative like you did, it will wait forever for any kind of response.

Use waittime based on your testing, so it is not to